# not able to read text file and print on webpage page in php

Tags: php

trying to read a text file which is appended by an another application on realtime and put it on a webpage . using php for this  its working fine if i put  echo $y;  which is commented out in code below. but if i comment it out its not processing the data of file. 
please help where i am wrong

```
 <?php
 static $x = 0;
 static $y=0;
 static $fileSize =0;

 if(file_exists($_POST["city-cs"].".txt")) {  
    $strHeading = "<h2> Alarms for central station " . $_POST["city-cs"] . "</h2>";
    echo $strHeading;
    $f = fopen( $_POST["city-cs"].".txt", "r");

// Read line from the text file and write the contents to the client
    while(true) {
        $y=filesize($_POST["city-cs"].".txt");  
        clearstatcache();
      // echo $y;           
        if($y>$fileSize) {  
            fseek($f,$x);
            while(!feof($f)) {     

                echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
                $x= ftell($f);      
            }
            $y=filesize($_POST["city-cs"].".txt");
            $fileSize = $y;
            clearstatcache();
        } 
    }
} else {
    echo "<h1> Central Station ".$_POST["city-cs"]." does not exist </h1>";
}
?>
```

On error log I get

> [11-May-2017 11:58:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\handler1.php on line 16 [11-May-2017 11:58:53 UTC] PHP Stack trace: [11-May-2017 11:58:53 UTC] PHP 1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\handler1.php:0

This is a sample of the file I am processing

```
15:08:36 <1> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06>
15:09:06 <2> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:09:36 <3> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:10:07 <4> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:10:37 <5> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:11:07 <6> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:11:37 <7> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:12:07 <8> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:12:37 <9> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06>
15:13:07 <10> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:13:37 <11> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06> 
15:14:07 <12> : [10]00sOKAYs@[13] <06>
```

Comment: You appear to be in a while loop `while (true)` that has no way of terminating itself !!!! My guess wait 30 seconds and look at the errors in the error log. Although that would have been my first _Thing to do_ before asking a question

Comment: You also seem to have made the reading of the file IMMENSLY complex when I dont see a need for it, although I, like everyone else, I have no idea how the file is structured

Comment: @RiggsFolly , on error log  : [11-May-2017 11:58:53 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\handler1.php on line 16

[11-May-2017 11:58:53 UTC] PHP Stack trace:

[11-May-2017 11:58:53 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\handler1.php:0

Comment: @RiggsFolly  but if i put statement "echo $y;"   its working fine  why ?   i am totally new in programming.

Comment: It does not work fine, it just echos something before it crashes

Comment: Show a sample of the file you are trying to process, and tell us what you want to get out of it. But edit this new info into your question please

Comment: Its timing out because the `while(true)` loop will run forever as you have no way of breaking out of it

Comment: 15:08:36 <1> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:09:06 <2> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:09:36 <3> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:10:07 <4> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:10:37 <5> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:11:07 <6> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:11:37 <7> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:12:07 <8> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:12:37 <9> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:13:07 <10> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:13:37 <11> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
15:14:07 <12> :  [10]00sOKAYs@[13]    <06>
this the sample

Comment: Does that file have newlines anywhere or is it all just one ling string

Comment: @RiggsFolly  on putting echo its printing the size of file and then the data available on text  file. but on removing that echo it does nothing .

Comment: yes , new line is there. every line starts with time (15:09)

Comment: So now, what do you want this script to output?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  just want  whenever there are new lines written on file by other background application, then my script should print that new data else wait.

Comment: But if this is a web page, you cannot wait indefinitely. The script will timeout.

Comment: Now I see why you had an infinite while loop in there

Comment: i just want to wait till session is there.  and my page is autorefreshing.

Comment: But you are not using the session

Comment: And a page refresh will run a new version of the script

Comment: i am new to these things @RiggsFolly please suggest something

Comment: I would use AJAX for this, it would give a better user experience as well as the page would not need to keep refreshing

Comment: any sample code i can find ? please suggest any link

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_ajax.htm

Comment: but not getting why its working when echo is there.